# How to add def variable into echo commnad inside a shell script in jenkins?

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

```
script {
                    now = new Date()
                    time = now.format("%D", TimeZone.getTimeZone('IST'))
                
                    CREATE = sh (
                        script: ' echo "curl -v -u Jbdi00QTpDnrEJ37IUy9:X -H \\"Content-Type: application/json\\" -d \' { \\"description\\": \\" Descrption of ticket\\", \\"subject\\": \\"Ticket from Jenkins ${time}\\", \\"email\\": \\" tom@outerspace.com \\", \\"priority\\": 1, \\"status\\": 2}\' -X POST \'https://srikartest1.freshpo.com/api/v2/tickets\' | python -m json.tool"',
                        returnStdout: true
                    )
                    echo "${CREATE}"
}
```

in the output the time is not inserting the echo command

output:

```
echo 'curl -v -u Jbdi00QTpDnrEJ37IUy9:X -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '\'' { "description": " Descrption of ticket", "subject": "Ticket from Jenkins ", "email": " tom@outerspace.com ", "priority": 1, "status": 2}'\'' -X POST '\''https://srikartest1.freshpo.com/api/v2/tickets'\'' | python -m json.tool'
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to escape the $ in groovy -

```
      script {
                    now = new Date()
                    time = now.format("dd", TimeZone.getTimeZone('IST'))

                    CREATE = $/ sh (
                        script: ' echo "curl -v -u Jbdi00QTpDnrEJ37IUy9:X -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d ' { "description": " Descrption of ticket", "subject": "Ticket from Jenkins ${time} ", "email": " tom@outerspace.com ", "priority": 1, "status": 2}' -X POST 'https://srikartest1.freshpo.com/api/v2/tickets' | python -m json.tool"',
                        returnStdout: true
                    )  /$
                    echo "${CREATE}"
}
```